# Why does Windows 10 replaces what's in the clipboard with a vandalised one?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, clipboard

Windows Explorer clearly says it cannot accept special characters (which is reasonable in a File Explorer), but If I copy the string "https://www.example.com" and paste it in the name field of a newly created document, my clipboard has been vandalised and the string is replaced with another string (when for example I paste it back in the browser).

To clarify, I create a new document in Explorer, double click it and dropped the string "https://www.example.com" there, Windows not only modifies the document name but the clipboard also and replaces "https://www.example.com" with "httpswww.example.com", when for example I paste it back into a browser. This isn't necessary big trouble but I'm only wondering why the programmer chose to do this.

Comment: The clipboard is not a single entity. It has multiple 'layers' depending on the precise content type. You need to clarify your actual actions & results. Additionally, copying from a browser header - especially something like Google - will replace your intended data with their huge ungainly referencing structure. Plugins are available to remove that $h!t€

Comment: "Drop the string there..." as a **filename**? Of course slashes are removed!!! That is not how you make an internet shortcut, nor how you modify a document itself.